# How to update Firefox?

Tags: firefox

How to update Firefox? As I remember, there used to be an 'update now' button in the options menu.

If it helps, this is on Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the current version(s) (for Windows, at least) you visit the About page to force an update check.

- Click the menu button.
- Click help (question mark)
- Select About Firefox.

The About Firefox window will open and Firefox will begin checking for updates and downloading them automatically.

[Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version)

Comment: It doesn't always work this way: for example, in the PortableApps version the About box does this, but it will not update properly and you need to use the PA updater; or in Ubuntu it does not look for updates in the About box, but is updated by canonical updates; or again in Android it is updated through PlayStore, etc, etc. The questioner has not told us enough about his environment.

Comment: @AFH The screenshot told he probably use Windows 7 or at least a skin/theme in Windows OS. As long as it's Windows then it isn't much different.

Comment: @AFH Feel free to augment my answer or place your own.  Perhaps request clarification from the OP?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - The screenshot wasn't showing when I made my comment. I agree, it does look like Windows, but we shouldn't have to do forensic analysis in order to answer a question.